# k8s - Significance of ReplicaSet matchLabel selector

Tags: kubernetes

Assuming deployment, replicaSet and pod are all 1:1:1 mapping.

```
deployment ==> replicaSet ==> Pod
```

When we do deployment, replicaSet adds `pod-template-hash` label to pods. So, this looks enough for a replicaSet to check if enough pods are running. Then what is the significance of replicaSet `matchLabels` selector? Why is it mandatory?

To explain for better understanding

For ex: I deploy an app with these labels. 2 pods are running

```
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
```

Now change label value of pod-template-hash to something else for one of the pods (changing to `testing` here). Now we immediately see another pod started. So replicaSet does not seem to care about `selector.matchLabels`

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
pod/nginx-app-b8b875889-cpnnr   1/1     Running   0          53s   app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=testing
pod/nginx-app-b8b875889-jlk6m   1/1     Running   0          53s   app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=b8b875889
pod/nginx-app-b8b875889-xblqr   1/1     Running   0          11s   app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=b8b875889

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE    LABELS
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   151d   component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes

NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   LABELS
deployment.apps/nginx-app   2/2     2            2           53s   app=nginx-app

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   LABELS
replicaset.apps/nginx-app-b8b875889   2         2         2       53s   app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=b8b875889
```

Comment: Does it answered by https://serverfault.com/questions/1007884/why-do-i-have-to-explicitely-define-labels-multiple-times ?

Comment: @Sirish. Thanks - not exactly clarify this question. So added more info to make it clear

Comment: @RamPrakash ReplicaSet seems to care about the labels right ? thats why it started a new pod with matching labels (along with pod template hash) ?

Comment: @confusedgenius, no. if it is looking for matchLabels, then we have 2 pods running already. no need to start another pod.

Comment: oh ok , the reason is once you create a deployment and when you look at it configuration ```kubectl get deployment nginx-app -o yaml``` you would see that "matchLabels" section contains "pod-template-hash: b8b875889" as well ( it gets added automatically) along with predefined labels in your user created yaml file .. hope this clarifies.

Comment: @confusedgenius, it still does not clarify. In this case deployment/replicaset does not have to make this matchLabels as a mandatory field and expects the user to provide an input. As I said `pod-template-hash` itself is enough for deployment/replicaSet. It asks me to provide a selector - but does not use it. is my question clear?

Comment: it does uses it  , one way to prove is change the "app=nginx-app" to "app=nginx-app1" for pod nginx-app-b8b875889-xblqr using ```kubectl label pod nginx-app-b8b875889-xblqr app=nginx-app1 --overwrite``` you will see rs creating a new pod

Comment: it is 'AND' of user label & pod-template-hash .

Comment: @confusedgenius my question is very simple. Why do we need an AND here. why not simply go with given selector? i am looking for specific use cases which explains the proper use of selector here.

Comment: pod-template-hash can not pre-calculated or pre-known before creating the deployment.example practical scenario :  requirement is  create deployment yaml file & service yaml file for that deployment  for an app. if we just depend on pod-templete-hash i can not create a service yaml before deploying the deployment(because one cannot guess pod-template-hash).

Comment: @confusedgenius, service does not need deployments/replicasets. service uses pod labels.

Comment: @RamPrakash now i understood your question ... Interesting one.sorry for many comments.Now i am also waiting for an answer to this :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let me summarize it. The whole discussion is about: Why deployment forces me to set matchLabels selector even though it could easly live without it, since its adding pod-template-hash and it would be totally fine with using only that.

After reading all the comments and all the discussion I decided to look in kubernetes documentation.

I will allow myself to quote k8s documentation about replicasets: [How a ReplicaSet works](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#how-a-replicaset-works)

> #### How a ReplicaSet works:
>
> [...]
>
> **A ReplicaSet is linked to its Pods via the Pods'**
> **metadata.ownerReferences field**, which specifies what resource the
> current object is owned by. All Pods acquired by a ReplicaSet have
> their owning ReplicaSet's identifying information within their
> ownerReferences field. It's through this link that the ReplicaSet
> knows of the state of the Pods it is maintaining and plans
> accordingly.

So does is mean that it's not using labels at all? Well, not exactly. Let's keep reading:

> A ReplicaSet identifies new Pods to acquire by using its selector. If
> there is a Pod that has no OwnerReference or the OwnerReference is not
> a Controller and it matches a ReplicaSet's selector, it will be
> immediately acquired by said ReplicaSet

Ouh, so it looks like it is using the selector only as an alternative to the first method.

Let's keep reading. Here is a quote from [Pod Selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#pod-selector) section:

> #### Pod Selector
>
> The .spec.selector field is a label selector. As
> discussed earlier **these are the labels used to identify potential Pods**
> **to acquire**

It looks like these labels are not used as a primary method to keep track of pod owned by the ReplicaSet, they are use to *"identify potential Pods to acquire"*. But what does it mean?

Why would ReplicaSet acquire pods it does not own? There is a section in documentation that tries to answer this very question: [Non-Template Pod acquisition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#non-template-pod-acquisitions)

> #### Non-Template Pod acquisitions
>
> While you can create bare Pods with no problems, it is strongly
> recommended to make sure that the bare Pods do not have labels which
> match the selector of one of your ReplicaSets. The reason for this is
> because a ReplicaSet is not limited to owning Pods specified by its
> template-- it can acquire other Pods in the manner specified in the
> previous sections.
>
> [...]
>
> As those Pods do not have a Controller (or any object) as their owner
> reference and match the selector of the [...] ReplicaSet, they will
> immediately be acquired by it.

Great, but this still does not answer the question: Why do I need to provide the selector? Couldn't it just use that hash?

Back in the past when there was a bug in k8s:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23170
so someone suggested the validation is needed: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23218
And so validation appeared:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23530

And it stayed with us to this day, even if today we probably could live without it.

Although I think its better that it's there because it minimizes the chances of overlaping labels in case of pod-template-hash collision for different RSs.

Comment: this is the most valuable answer ever about replica set + pod  acquiring mechanism. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

one use case why we use pod-label "AND" pod-template-hash as Selector may be to handle the replicasets during updates/roll-back etc..

eg:-

In your scenario, the replicaset currently uses Selector app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=b8b875889.
consider the deployment is being updated to a later version of nginx image, as part of the upgrade it creates a new replicaset in the background which uses same selector but with new pod-template-hash, meaning the selector for the new replicaset will be "app=nginx-app,pod-template-hash=XXXXXXXX". As part of the upgrade the pods from old replicaset will be terminated and new pods will be created in the new replicaset. As the pod label (app=nginx-app) is common for both these replicasets, to manage them effectively and independently we need to use another selector which is unique for these replicasets. This is achieved by using pod-template-hash along with pod-label as selector.

Comment: Relevant documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template-hash-label