# How does k8s correlate ReplicaSet and Pods?

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have the following k8s config file with 2 identical deployments only different by name.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  name: hello-world-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-2
          image: rancher/hello-world:v0.1.2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 100M
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  name: hello-world-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-2
          image: rancher/hello-world:v0.1.2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 100M
```

As I understand, k8s correlate ReplicaSets and Pods by their label. Therefore, with the above configuration, I guess there will be some problem or k8s will forbid this configuration.
However, it turns out everything is fine. Apart from the labels, are there something else k8s is using to correlate ReplicaSet and Pods?

Comment: thats not exactly right. it also takes in consideration the pod template hash. which is why it works. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397373/k8s-significance-of-replicaset-matchlabel-selector for morre information

Comment: @meaningqo Thx, but the template of the two deployments are the same hence their pod-template-hash are also the same.

Comment: you are right. however, it still works. i am not 100% sure why but it seems to also take the name of the deployment into consideration as well. 
just tested it out on my minikube instance

Comment: @meaningqo I have the same guess but I am not 100% sure. That's why I ask this question.  ╮(╯_╰)╭

Comment: what are the differences in both these deployments full json outputs except timestamps?